# Как работать с огромной json базой?

Tags: node.js, json

База отелей в json, 25гб, не могу понять как с ней работать.
Загрузил её в mangodb, создал server.js.
Читается, но когда делаю find по ней. Манго долго пытается прочитать. Видимо не очень решение.
Подскажите, как вообще работать с огромной json базой?

Comment: Смотря что там у тебя хранится и в какой "структуре"...

Comment: Добавить индексы?

Comment: Переложить данные из json в реляционную БД, разнести сущности по табличкам, постоить индексы и радоваться?

Comment: Ну, не знаю в чем проблема у автора, но прям сейчас в проде монга хранит на 20гб+- данных (около 2млн документов), по индексу ищется всё моментально :)

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт в области БД.. 25 гиг для БД вообще мелочи) наверняка индексов не хватает

Comment: Нужно знать структуру данных и какие запросы будут выполняться. На основании этого сделать выбор БД: реляционная, документная, колоночная. Ну и конечно, индексы рулят!